# Is it possible to save UILocalNotification Objects to plist or sqlite database, or somewhere else like NSUserDefaults?

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

I want to save the objects of UILocalNotifications such as following, preferably somewhere from where I can retrieve it and could be able to save multiple UILocalNotification objects

```
    UILocalNotification *local=[[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    [local setAlertBody:str];
    [local setFireDate:dat];
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"some_id_to_cancel" forKey:@"ID"];
    local.userInfo = infoDict;
    //local.hasAction=NO;
    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:local];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:local];
    [local release];
```

Now I want to save local object somewhere such as plist or any storages from where I could get retrieve them.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:local toFile:@"path_to_file_where_to_save"];
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more, what is going on in one line statement and what be argument types?

Comment: and how will i retrieve it, hope you will give a better code with good explanation @moonlight

Comment: I think you will find more detailed information in this  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i

Answer (score 1):

Since `UILocalNotification` conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol, then, yes.

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

> The NSCoding protocol declares the two methods that a class must implement so that instances of that class can be encoded and decoded. This capability provides the basis for archiving (where objects and other structures are stored on disk) and distribution (where objects are copied to different address spaces).

Comment: I have looked, now reading it, as I will solve, I will upvote Sir :-)